# Updating multiple tables from user defined table

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

Hi I have following stored procedure which works fine, using user defined table type.

```
ALTER procedure [dbo].[wl]
@test [dbo].[testType] readonly 
 as 
Begin
merge into t_values as Target
using @test as Source 
on Target.Id =Source.Id
when matched then 
update set target.Num=Source.Num
when not matched then 
insert (Id,Num)
values (Source.Id,  Source.Num);
End
```

What I have are two more tables test2 and test3 where I need to update some values from source.
I am not sure how I can do that. 
Basically my goal is when a condition is matched update or insert values into all three tables because of foreign key relations. Please let me know how I can do that. Thanks

Comment: Is the Sql Server 2012? And why the c# tag? Even if you control this with c# code, your question does not involve it at all.

Comment: While set-based logic is generally preferable, there are times and places to use a cursor, and this may be one. Cursors can sometimes be more human-readable and maintainable. If you only need to take action on a few rows, you can make the cursor select only those specific rows of your source table joined with your multiple target tables. Or, if you have to, you can retreat to plain old IF statements.

Comment: @criticalfix, I have to stress: cursors are VERY slow when it comes to a large dataset. Choose your situations carefully.

Comment: Yak to cursors.  This can be handled using "set based".

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the "output" clause to capture the "keys" of the rows that are inserted.......right after they are inserted.

Here is an example...not an exact match....but shows the idea.

http://granadacoder.wordpress.com/2008/12/10/sqlserver20052008-output-clause-in-insertupdatedelete-statements/

EDIT:

Here is an example that I did.......where I insert a "Person" (parent entity) and some email addresses (child entity).
I shred xml, your data-table should be similar.

The key is that I "audit" (with the output clause) the IDENTITY being generated with I insert a Person.....but I keep that info in tack with the natural unique identifier (the SSN in this example).  When I insert the email addresses, I have the IDENTITY's of the Person's I inserted.

My #TempTables would be "real tables" in your final solution.  My @VariableTable is the "audit" table that collects and stores the info gathered by the "output" clause.

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#DestinationPersonParentTable') IS NOT NULL
begin
        drop table #DestinationPersonParentTable
end



IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#DestinationEmailAddressPersonChildTable') IS NOT NULL
begin
        drop table #DestinationEmailAddressPersonChildTable
end



CREATE TABLE #DestinationPersonParentTable
(
PersonParentSurrogateIdentityKey int not null identity (1001, 1), 
SSNNaturalKey int, 
HireDate datetime
)



declare @PersonOutputResultsAuditTable table
(
SSNNaturalKey int, 
PersonParentSurrogateIdentityKeyAudit int
)





CREATE TABLE #DestinationEmailAddressPersonChildTable
(
DestinationChildSurrogateIdentityKey int not null identity (3001, 1), 
PersonParentSurrogateIdentityKeyFK int, 
EmailAddressValueNaturalKey varchar(64),
EmailAddressType int
)





-- Declare XML variable

DECLARE @data XML;

-- Element-centered XML

SET @data = N'
<root xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <Person>
        <SSN>222222222</SSN>
        <HireDate>2002-02-02</HireDate>
    </Person>

    <Person>
        <SSN>333333333</SSN>
        <HireDate>2003-03-03</HireDate>
    </Person>

    <EmailAddress>
        <SSNLink>222222222</SSNLink>
        <EmailAddressValue>g@g.com</EmailAddressValue>
        <EmailAddressType>1</EmailAddressType>
    </EmailAddress>

    <EmailAddress>
        <SSNLink>222222222</SSNLink>
        <EmailAddressValue>h@h.com</EmailAddressValue>
        <EmailAddressType>2</EmailAddressType>
    </EmailAddress>

    <EmailAddress>
        <SSNLink>333333333</SSNLink>
        <EmailAddressValue>a@a.com</EmailAddressValue>
        <EmailAddressType>1</EmailAddressType>
    </EmailAddress>

    <EmailAddress>
        <SSNLink>333333333</SSNLink>
        <EmailAddressValue>b@b.com</EmailAddressValue>
        <EmailAddressType>2</EmailAddressType>
    </EmailAddress>

</root>

';




INSERT INTO #DestinationPersonParentTable ( SSNNaturalKey ,  HireDate )

output inserted.SSNNaturalKey , inserted.PersonParentSurrogateIdentityKey  into @PersonOutputResultsAuditTable ( SSNNaturalKey , PersonParentSurrogateIdentityKeyAudit)

SELECT T.parentEntity.value('(SSN)[1]', 'INT') AS SSN,
       T.parentEntity.value('(HireDate)[1]', 'datetime') AS HireDate
FROM @data.nodes('root/Person') AS T(parentEntity)
/* add a where not exists check on the natural key */
where not exists (
    select null from #DestinationPersonParentTable innerRealTable where innerRealTable.SSNNaturalKey = T.parentEntity.value('(SSN)[1]', 'INT') )
;

/* Optional.  You could do a UPDATE here based on matching the #DestinationPersonParentTableSSNNaturalKey = T.parentEntity.value('(SSN)[1]', 'INT')
You could Combine INSERT and UPDATE using the MERGE function on 2008 or later.
 */


select 'PersonOutputResultsAuditTable_Results' as Label, * from @PersonOutputResultsAuditTable


INSERT INTO #DestinationEmailAddressPersonChildTable (  PersonParentSurrogateIdentityKeyFK ,  EmailAddressValueNaturalKey , EmailAddressType )
SELECT  par.PersonParentSurrogateIdentityKeyAudit , 
        T.childEntity.value('(EmailAddressValue)[1]', 'varchar(64)') AS EmailAddressValue,
        T.childEntity.value('(EmailAddressType)[1]', 'INT') AS EmailAddressType
FROM @data.nodes('root/EmailAddress') AS T(childEntity)
/* The next join is the "trick".  Join on the natural key (SSN)....**BUT** insert the PersonParentSurrogateIdentityKey into the table */
join @PersonOutputResultsAuditTable par on par.SSNNaturalKey = T.childEntity.value('(SSNLink)[1]', 'INT')
where not exists (
    select null from #DestinationEmailAddressPersonChildTable innerRealTable where innerRealTable.PersonParentSurrogateIdentityKeyFK = par.PersonParentSurrogateIdentityKeyAudit AND  innerRealTable.EmailAddressValueNaturalKey = T.childEntity.value('(EmailAddressValue)[1]', 'varchar(64)'))
;



print '/#DestinationPersonParentTable/'
select * from #DestinationPersonParentTable


print '/#DestinationEmailAddressPersonChildTable/'
select * from #DestinationEmailAddressPersonChildTable


select SSNNaturalKey , HireDate , '---' as Sep1 , EmailAddressValueNaturalKey , EmailAddressType , '---' as Sep2, par.PersonParentSurrogateIdentityKey as ParentPK , child.PersonParentSurrogateIdentityKeyFK as childFK from #DestinationPersonParentTable par join #DestinationEmailAddressPersonChildTable child
on par.PersonParentSurrogateIdentityKey = child.PersonParentSurrogateIdentityKeyFK



IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#DestinationPersonParentTable') IS NOT NULL
begin
        drop table #DestinationPersonParentTable
end


IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#DestinationEmailAddressPersonChildTable') IS NOT NULL
begin
        drop table #DestinationEmailAddressPersonChildTable
end
```

Comment: I know it's your own blog, but it might help to summarize the code here, incase you 404.

Comment: My comments added enough info, in case my blog dies.  But I'll edit on your suggestion.

Comment: http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2183/using-insert-output-in-a-sql-server-transaction/

Comment: Edit made using xml, but the concept should be the same.